# ASP.NET MVC windows authentication integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory, asp.net-membership

We've got an internal job tracking system which is used by 10 or so people. Currently we use Forms authentication. The login form consists of a textbox where the user enters their name, and then we set the Forms authentication cookie. There is no password.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
```

We're now able to use the user's name to save to the database and display on screen in the various controllers by calling User.Identity.Name.

This simple approach has been perfectly adequate so far, but now we're ready to start authenticating users with active directory. We want users to be able to login with their domain username and password.

So we enable windows authentication.

The problem however, is that now User.Identity.Name takes the format of DOMAIN\USER. It is also hypothetically possible that one day some user is going to have a different domain username than their username in our job tracking system.

What is the best way to assign a "job tracker username" to the user, so that they can login with their domain username, but the job tracker can log jobs and display the persons name using a different username.

I know I can use session, or I can make a call to the database, but is there a more correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I switched to Forms authentication since Windows authentication doesn't work on some android phones. I also use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider to authenticate the user against the domain. See my other questions on this subject for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First decide where you're going to store the info.  This could be a database, Active Directory, or whatever.  Then decide how you're going to maintain it (e.g. administrative UI, probably protected by role-based security.  Or if it's stored in Active Directory, you may be able to delegate this job to your AD administrators).

Afterwards its trivial to do the lookup, and possibly cache the looked up values in Session, or perhaps in Cache.

Comment: I suppose storing it in the database and caching it makes sense, but then how do I retrieve it?

Comment: What I mean is, is there a place I can set it and retrieve it easily like User.Identity.Name

Comment: If you want something built-in, you could use ASP.NET Profile properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs(v=vs.100).aspx .  Otherwise, just roll your own.